# PowerShell/Canopy cause differences in code output?

Tags: python

I am currently working my way through Learn Python The Hard Way and came across this code.

```
print "How old are you?",
age = raw_input()
print "How tall are you?",
height = raw_input()
```

When using this code in Canopy I get the output:

```
How old are you?
5
 How tall are you?
5
```

Whereas using PowerShell gives me:

```
How old are you? 5
How tall are you? 6
```

How can the same code cause Canopy to display the output in 4 lines while PowerShell uses 2. Is one disregarding the commas after the print statement or is this something trivial?Also what is causing the extra space on the second question in canopy? (I am using Python 2.7.6)
Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Powershell and Canopy are different IDE's ... they may not (in fact I know that they DO NOT) use the same syntax and as such, will format output to console differently from one another. Canopy is recognizing the comma and treating it (or at least somewhere in there interpreting) as a newline character. Powershell is not and I suspect this stems from the intended use cases of Powershell and Canopy i.e Powershell is Microsoft's attempt at creating something like a bash shell with builtin command line and editing capabilities and Canopy was created as an IDE.  Hope this helps!